# Get value from map and modify map in same scope

Tags: rust

Here is a simple program which looks up previous value in `map` and puts a new value into it. It won't compile as the first lookup immutably borrows `map` and `insert` wants to mutably borrow `map`.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<i32, i32> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(0, 0);

    (1..5).for_each(|x| {
        let prev = map.get(&(x - 1)).unwrap();
        map.insert(x, (prev + 1) * 10);
    });

    map.iter().for_each(|(k, v)| println!("{} -> {}", k, v));
}
```

The problem can be solved by using `clone()` on to get `prev` as

```
let prev = map.get(&(x - 1)).unwrap().clone();
```

and get the output as:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 10
2 -> 110
3 -> 1110
4 -> 11110
```

What can I do to not use `clone()` here?

Comment: use a scope if you don't use NLL, https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f2754b8bb3c0e02d357cd4fdbcb03d5a

Comment: The code you've provided [compiles as-is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc4a7c9b6200933f4b615ad6e5667145). Upgrade your Rust version and switch to Rust 2018.

Comment: @Stargateur Can you please post this as answer so that I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: As posted by @Stargateur the sniappet clearly explains how lexical lifetimes can help to understand use of each variable clearly.

Non Lexical Lifetimes (NLL) does help to write code easier but the scoping here seems a better idea and more idiomatic IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HashMap::get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) returns `Option<&V>`, which you unwrap, getting `&V`, so you end up with `prev` being an immutable reference that points inside `map`. That's why you have an immutable borrow of `map`. The type of `prev` is `&i32`.

To solve your problem, you can dereference that reference:

```
let prev = *map.get(&(x - 1)).unwrap();
```

In this case, the type of prev is `i32`, and it is just a value on the stack. It does not point inside `map` => you don't borrow `map` immutably so you can borrow `map` mutably in the next line.

Your original code works just fine if you enable Rust 2018 edition, because of [non-lexical lifetimes support](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html#non-lexical-lifetimes).

Note that `HashMap` is not sorted, so the output lines are produced in arbitrary order. If you need sorting, you can consider using `BTreeMap`.

If you don't want to use either `Copy` (via `*`) or `Clone` at all, and don't want to switch to Rust 2018, you can do the following:

```
let value_to_insert = {
    let prev = map.get(&(x - 1)).unwrap();
    (prev + 1) * 10
}
map.insert(x, value_to_insert)
```

This is pretty much the same thing non-lexical lifetimes would do for you automatically in Rust 2018.

Comment: Updated. IMHO this is pointless for the values of i32 though.

Comment: De-referencing with `*` operator is same as `clone()` which doesn't answer the question.

Code snippet posted by @Stargateur actually solves it.